# Multiprocessing implemented but only one core works - Python

Tags: python-3.x

The following code was obviously written to get a speed improvement by using all 4 cores of my PC. Unfortunately, only one core starts working. I really just used the common code examples and adapted it for my problem but I can't see the mistake..

```
import scipy as sp
import ubertool
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import bwtools
from glob import glob
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

path=r'X:\Google Drive\Promotion_encrypted\Experimente\2016\SHHG_JETI200\FocusChromatic2016\20161114\Whole'
liste_bilder=glob(path + r'/*.png')
length=sp.size(liste_bilder)
area_array=[]

def areacalc(i):
    area=bwtools.AreaFWHM(liste_bilder[i])
    return area

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool=Pool(processes=4)
    result=pool.map(areacalc,range(length))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(result)
```

Comment: You can use "win32process.SetProcessAffinityMask(handle, mask)" to force a process to use a specific core.

Comment: It's not about using a specific one but about using all cores of my PC to speed the programm up..

Comment: If you have 8 cores for example, assign process K to core K % 8